# Whats the difference between type babel and jsx

Tags: html, reactjs

I just started using React JS ... I'm sorry but I am confused on what is the difference between type="text/babel" and type="text/jsx"

and when do I use them.. please help me understand.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Babel is a transpiler](https://babeljs.io/) that turns input code into "pure" JavaScript.

[JSX is a syntax sugar](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) over JavaScript. You write .jsx and transpile it to .js using a transpiler (typically, Babel).

When you write `text/babel` you are saying to the Babel library that you want to transpile that script into pure JavaScript.

In case you write `text/jsx` you are saying your script is in .jsx and you need a transpiler to parse your code.

If you want to write .jsx and/or ES6 without configuring a bundler like webpack or browserify, load Babel through a CDN and use `text/babel` for simplicity.

Comment: thank you for your very definitive answer sir.... may I ask... If i would run a jsx code from another file... should I save it as .js? and would it run.. if i just call it in <script src="example.js" type="text/jsx">

Comment: If you run a JSX code you'll need a transpiler, otherwise you'll have syntax error. If you are unsure about having a transpiler, write plain JavaScript.