# different between "text/babel" and "text/jsx"

Tags: reactjs, redux

Im new to React and would like to ask the different between

```
  <script type="text/babel" ></script>
  <script   type="text/jsx" ></script>
```

my code works perfectly for both types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whats the difference between type babel and jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274629/whats-the-difference-between-type-babel-and-jsx)

Answer (score 1):

about  tag, you can see:

[HTML script type Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_type.asp)

Browser default is text/javascript

**JSX**

It is called JSX, and it is a syntax extension to JavaScript. We recommend using it with React to describe what the UI should look like. JSX may remind you of a template language, but it comes with the full power of JavaScript.

[Introducing JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

**Babel**

Babel is a JavaScript compiler.

[Deprecating JSTransform and react-tools](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html)